# Horizontal scrollbar with flex box items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 6 images inside a container with `display: flex`, so the width of the container is divided on the 6 images.

I want to show 2 images and part of the 3rd, while the 3 others are next to them at the right but not shown until the user scrolls to the right.

I hide the horizontal scrollbar, but I want to keep the scrolling functions, but as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f70yxrzm/), the 6 images are displayed.

How to only show 2 images and part of the 3rd with the other 3 hidden at the right next to the first 3?

Here is the code:

```css
.images {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dae2e4;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.images__gallery {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: -3px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.images__gallery-item {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 1%;
  flex-basis: 32%;
  height: 25vw;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #dae2e4;
}

.images__gallery-item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  top: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.images__title {
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  color: #707a81;
}

@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 24%;
    height: 20vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 530px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 19%;
    height: 16vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 16%;
    height: 12.5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar__frame">
  <div class="images sidebar__block">
    <div class="images__title">Images:</div>
    <div class="images__gallery">
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/150" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/120" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/105" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/122" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/195" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .images-->
</aside>
```

How to hide the horizontal scrollbar in this case?

Answer (score 6):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items can shrink in order to prevent overflow of the container. You can disable this feature with `flex-shrink: 0`.

Add this to your code:

```
.images__gallery-item {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, DO you know how to hide the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: You mean when there aren't enough items to fill the container? Try `overflow-x: auto`.

Comment: When I scroll the scrollbar appears, I don't want it to appear at all, But still having the scrolling feature

Comment: `images__gallery` has `overflow-x: scroll` and `overflow-y: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Your container element needs to have a maximum width of the size you want to show, and the scroll bar on the x axis. Your image container needs to be explicitly made wider than the containing element:

```css
.sidebar__frame {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidebar__block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}


/* .images {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dae2e4;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
*/

.images__gallery {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin: -3px;
  min-width: 700px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.images__gallery-item {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 1%;
  flex-basis: 32%;
  height: 25vw;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #dae2e4;
}

.images__gallery-item img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000%;
  right: -1000%;
  top: -1000%;
  bottom: -1000%;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.images__title {
  line-height: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  color: #707a81;
}

@media (min-width: 420px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 24%;
    height: 20vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 530px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 19%;
    height: 16vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .images__gallery-item {
    flex-basis: 16%;
    height: 12.5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar sidebar__frame">
  <div class="images sidebar__block">
    <div class="images__title">Images:</div>
    <div class="images__gallery">
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/150" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/100" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/120" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/105" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/122" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="images__gallery-item">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/195" alt="Wikimedia">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .images-->
</aside>
```

Comment: Do you know how to hide the horizontal scrollbar, But keeping the scrolling feature?

Comment: I guess it's a bit of a hack, but I've made the very outer container hidden on overflow, then the second container auto, and then shifted the margin in to cover the scroll bar. Hover your mouse over the images and hold shift while you scroll and it should scroll horizontally.